# Javascript: manipulate individual markers on Fusion Tables layer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

I have a Fusion Table of about 1000 entries, and I show them on a map using a FusionTablesLayer. I want to produce a list of the five closest markers to the center of the map. Clicking a list item should produce an info window for the corresponding marker. It looks a lot like the first sample on this site:
https://developers.google.com/maps/location-based-apps

But if I remember correctly, Layers don't allow acces to individual markers. On the other hand, if I use an Overlay the rendering of the 1000 markers has to be done client-side and obviously I don't want that.

How do I do this? Make an Overlay for the 5 markers and a FusionTablesLayer for the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/orderby_test_gviz_numbered.html) showing the 10 closest markers to the center of the map.

Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_AfricaMap_kml_sidebar.html) that does the sidebar.

Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/orderby_test_gviz_numbered_sidebar.html) that combines the two.

Comment: Sweet. Didn't think you could create an info window out of nothing, but it makes sense. I underestimated the power of the API!

Comment: While the question is correctly answered, note that the use of the Google Visualization API limits you to 500 rows.  There is now an "official" JSONP API to Fusion Tables which does not have this limitation.

Comment: For small searches (5 closest results was the question), the 500 limit on returned values will not be an issue.  I don't see the limit ever being an issue for realistic spatial queries (but I could be wrong, I'm sure someone can find a reason to show the 500+ closest results to a place).

Comment: Plus, I've been using the JSONP API anyhow. :)

Comment: Too bad those links don't work anymore =( Looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: The owner of the table removed it.  I will see if I can create a table that will make the examples work again.  However, the code should still work if you have a table with data in it, can you provide your table id (and make it public, or at least a public version)?

Comment: Examples fixed (but the new table contains KML in a "geometry" column, and is in a different location of the world)